# PG::Error: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I just did a dump of my staging databse, than did pg_restore on my local postgres databse to get them to line up. All the data went through.

Now when I try to query in the Rails console, I get errors.

```
Artist.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "artists" 
=> 668
```

**

```
Artist.last
  Artist Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" ORDER BY "artists"."" DESC LIMIT 1
PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...T  "artists".* FROM "artists"  ORDER BY "artists"."" DESC LI...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "artists".* FROM "artists"  ORDER BY "artists"."" DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...T  "artists".* FROM "artists"  ORDER BY "artists"."" DESC LI...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "artists".* FROM "artists"  ORDER BY "artists"."" DESC LIMIT 1
from /Users/ryanrebo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec'
```

I get the same error on all other Models. I also cannot use `find(id)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `order by artists.`? Where's the field name. you can't order by table, it has to be `table.field`

Comment: Ditto. Perhaps what you are aiming for is "ORDER BY Name" (Name being a column in your table) or something like that...

Comment: That's just the output of calling `Artist.last`. I use ActiveRecord's `last` method all the time, never had an issue

Comment: @RyanRebo: have you restarted your server after dumping? The error is really strange. Also run bundle install just in case. And pull latest changes. In other words, make sure your project is in sync and started from a new console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this by dropping and then re-creating the local database, re-running the migrations, and passing `--data-only` as an option on `pg_restore`.
Thanks for the help y'all. That was a strange error.

Answer (score 10):

The error occurs because "artists" table does not have a primary key which is used for the order by:

> Artist Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" ORDER BY "artists"."" DESC LIMIT 1

Add a primary key to fix by adding the following code block to a rails migration or run the alter table command in the database:

> execute <<-SQL
>    ALTER TABLE assets ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
>   SQL

where id is the primary key of "artists".

Comment: Thank you. I had this problem with a view I created, and added `self.primary_key = 'id'` to the model for the view and it worked.

Comment: I also had this issue of the primary key not being assigned. In my instance the model was a vendor migration which did not inherit from ApplicationRecord/ActiveRecord so I monkeypatched the vendor model by defining a `self.primary_key` method that returns `"id"` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is kinda patch. It is not what you want to do when you have a dump. You should run

1) rake db:drop

2) rake db:create

3) dump your data with pg_restore and no need in --data-only

Comment: db:setup to create tables, and then insert data back. I've had same issue when moved the app from server with PG 9.5 to server with PG 10